# How to use Ajax to Validate email or username as unique in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

This is my UserController where I check if the username exist in the database and return a json message accordingly. What i want is an ajax request to post to this controller and to return a message to a HTML form if the username exist or doesn't exist in the database.

```js
 public function postSignUp(Request $request)
{


    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'last_name' => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'birthday' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'state' => 'required'
    ]);


    $username = $request->input('username', '');
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    // if the user was found, this will be true;
    // if the user wasn't found, $user will be null and this will be false
    if ($user) {
        return json_encode(false);
    } else {
        return json_encode(true);
    }
```

I was hoping to get a little help with this issue since I been searching the web for hours trying to figure this out.

I am currently building a logging web app with laravel 5.2 but I can't figure out how to use Ajax to do my front end validation. I found the following code online and did a little modifications to meet my needs but nothing seems to be working.

I am trying to verify the username field as a unique field. In other words, if the username exist in the database i want to let my users know before they submit the form. Can anyone help?

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        //register is the form id.
        $("#register").validate({
            rules: {
              /*username is the name of the field
              that I want to validate using ajax*/
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    rangelength: [6, 15],
                    remote: {
                        url: "{{ url('App/Http/Controllers/UserController/postSignUp') }}",
                        type: "post"
                    }
                }
            },
            errorClass: "has-danger",
            validClass: "has-success",
            //success: "valid",

            highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).fadeOut(function () {
                    $(element).fadeIn();
                });
                $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass(errorClass);
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass(errorClass);
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where's your description of what exactly the problem is, what you've done so far to troubleshoot and debug and where you got stuck?  You can't just post a bunch of code and expect us to know what the detailed question is?

Comment: Hey jfriend00, thanks for your quick reply. I am trying to validate my signup form using ajax in laravel 5.2. I already have the server validation but i cannot figure out the front end validation. The code i posted above is a good example of what i have done so for but i cannot troubleshoot the error because i am not getting any error from the script.

Comment: Please add words to your question (use the edit link to fix it) that explain exactly what you expect to be happening, where you think the ajax call is and what you've done to investigate the problem so far.  Right now your question refers to an ajax call and there is no obvious ajax call in your code.  You're leaving far too much for us to guess.  If the ajax call is in the validation library, then explain exactly what you expect to happen and maybe even supply a reference to the validation doc that explains how this is supposed to be configured and how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Hey I added some more details as request. I am not sure if that's enough but that's everything i got so far. Do you need more information?

Comment: What validation library are you using and where's a link to the documentation for it that shows how to configure it to use an ajax call for field validation?

Comment: Hey, I added another part of my validation and here is the link to the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it just make more since to add a unique constraint to the database?

Comment: Yes, but how would the user know if the username exists? I just want to implement a better user experience by letting them know that the username exists before they even submit the form.

Comment: Hey guys, 

Thanks for the help I figure it out.